# Car Drag Strip Simulation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, velocity, simulations, differentiation

I have written an iPhone App for to our local drag strip.
I'm trying to write a physics based information and simulation page duplicating the time slip you receive when you make a pass at a 1/4 mile track. To start, a simple top down 2D view showing the car going down the track straight along with an information log of the physics of the run. An example of my time slip,

60 ft - 1.65 secs
330 ft - 4.84 secs
660 ft - 7.54 secs
1000 ft - 9.89 secs
1320 ft - 11.89 secs

I've inputted this in to Excel, graphed it, added a three order polynomial equation to be displayed. So, I have my equation of motion.

> y=-0.2705x^3 + 10.623x^2 + 23.016x - 1.9203

I then went to a Wolfram web calculator to get the first derivative equation for speed.

> y = -0.8115 x^2 + 21.246 x + 23.016

I then went back to Wolfram to get first derivative equation of speed (velocity)

> y = 21.246 - 1.623 x

For now, I'm just trying to understand what information I can obtain from my time slips.

Does the above look reasonable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran the same data through Microsoft Excel, and note that you "over-parameterized" your model.  A quadratic equation matches the standard physics approach to your problem, and gives an almost perfect fit to the data.  The equations that I got from this are:

$x = 5.0421t^2 + 55.507t - 48.434 ft$, where x is distance travelled.

Since velocity is $dx/dt$, the equation for velocity is:
$v = 10.0842t + 55.507 ft/s$

Finally, since acceleration is $dv/dt$, the acceleration is constant at $a=10.0842ft/s^2$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will look this over. One thing that doesn't make sense, the acceleration formula you posted, it doesn't have a variable. How am I gonna use it to determine my acceleration at any moment in time?

Comment: That is because, based on your data, the acceleration is constant.

Comment: This is because, based on your model, acceleration is constant. This is not a good model of wheeled vehicles powered by internal combustion and subject to aerodynamic drag.

Comment: Agreed ... and the original data are not so good either.  The data indicate that the car started at a negative x position with an initial velocity.

Comment: Hmmm, that confuses me. The data is all we are given, I have no control over that. The car is accelerating, it is not constant.If I use the original equations I posted, I get acceleration that starts off aggressive and slowly drops off, reflecting the pass, ignoring the initial zero position. My errors, comparing actual distances measured, are about 9% at 60 feet and drop off reasonably from there.I'll move on to modeling the run to incorporate kinetics and kinematics. I sincerely appreciate your responses.

Comment: @ThomasC., I usually try to use the lowest order polynomial that fits the data.  A quadratic equation fits your data EXTREMELY well, which, as David Hammen has already stated, seems to imply no wind drag.  In addition, I already noted that the data seem "suspect", as the equation would be expected to be $x = 1/2at^2$, taking into account that the starting position is 0 meters and the starting velocity is 0 m/s.  If wind drag existed in the data, I would expect a fairly large drop in acceleration, especially as speed increased.  Inquire as to the source of the data.

Comment: @DavidWhite -- A quadratic does not fit very well, particularly so when you add the initial point (0.0, 0.0) to the dataset. These data are not suspect. They are quite consistent with a high end sports car (a supercharged 2006 Mustang GT). A cubic model reflects reality and does very nicely in modeling that car. A cubic model yields 3.55 sec for a 0-60 time and a final speed of 109.8 mph, both quite consistent with that car. A quadratic model yields 3.78 sec for a 0-60 time and a final speed of 123.5 mph. Those numbers are inconsistent.

Comment: One other nice feature of the quadratic model is the initial state. Modeling as $at^3+bt^2+ct$ and excluding the initial point results in an initial velocity of 14.9 mph. Modeling as $at^3+bt^2+ct+d$ and including the initial point results in an initial position of -1.8 feet and an initial velocity of 15.6 mph. That is perfectly consistent with a drag start. The goal in a drag start is to start the car moving prior to the light turning green, with the rear tires crossing the start line a tiny, tiny bit after the light turns green.

Comment: @DavidHammen, I only produced a data fit for the data that were posted.  If the point (0,0) is in the data set, the OP should post it.  In addition, for your latest post, you quoted a quadratic model but posted a cubic equation.  Please clarify.  Also, please give me a brief description of a "drag start".  You imply that the car is already moving when the green light is given.

Comment: @DavidWhite - That was a typo. I should have written "One other nice feature of the cubic model ..." And yes, the car is already moving (or should be moving) when the green light is shown. A driver who waits for the light to turn green before starting to move has already lost the race. There's nothing wrong *per se* with a driver starting to move before the light turns green. Problems arise only if the rear wheels cross the start line before the light turns green.

Comment: A brief description of the start: The two cars (sometimes just one car) roll forward so the front wheels are in front of the start line, detected by a laser. The cars then come to a stop. The starter then starts the light sequence. Amateurs get a nice predictable sequence, three yellow lights, one at a time, followed by a green light, separated by a half second each. (Pros get all three yellows at once.) A fault occurs if the front of a rear tire crosses the start line before the green light is shown, once again detected by lasers.

Comment: Thanks.  I've seen drag racing on TV, but I didn't realize that the drivers could pop the clutch before the green light.

Answer (score 0):

> An example of my time slip,
>
> 60 ft - 1.65 secs

You are excluding a very important piece of data, which is the car's initial state, 0 ft at 0 seconds (or something very close to that). There are a couple of ways to address this.

One is to simply add that initial point to the dataset. If you do that and model the position (in feet) as a cubic function of time (in seconds), a least squares fit yields
$$x(t) = -0.26936508\,t^3 + 10.61434527\,t^2 + 22.94463215\,t -1.80807144$$
With only six data points and four parameters, this is dangerously close to an overfit. On the other hand, there are some nice features from this model. The initial acceleration is 21.2 ft/s<sup>2</sup>, or 2/3 *g*. The acceleration at the quarter mile (1320 feet) is a bit over 2 ft/s<sup>2</sup>. This is a peppy bike or high performance sports car, but not a dragster.

Another approach is to use a model that forces the initial position to be 0 at t=0. In this case, you don't want to add 0,0 to the dataset. Fitting a cubic with a zero constant term results in
$$x(t) = -0.27751093\,t^3 + 10.7907414\,t^2 + 21.8374885\,t$$
This has a slightly higher residual error (2.7 feet RMS), but retains the nice feature of an initial high acceleration and a rather low acceleration at the quarter mile.

> For now, I'm just trying to understand what information I can obtain from my time slips.

You can also estimate your 0 to 60 time. The first model yields a value of 3.54 seconds, the second, 3.55 seconds. A peppy bike or a high performance sports car, but definitely not a dragster.

Comment: The car in this example is my Roush supercharged 2006 Mustang GT with an automatic transmission. It is sleek, but experiences "normal" aerodynamic drag. And yes, a drag race starts at position 0.00 and o.00 velocity. I also calculated the same zero to 60MPH times, which I want to include in the app analysis.

Comment: @DavidHammen. I'm using a class in my app from (https://github.com/KingIsulgard/iOS-Polynomial-Regression) to obtain my formula's, how would I go about "fitting a cubic with a zero constant term"?

Comment: @ThomasC. - I used python numpy, where it's incredibly easy. I put your time and position data in `tv` and `xv`, respectively. Then `p = np.poly1d(np.append(np.linalg.lstsq([[t**3,t**2,t] for t in tv], xv)[0], 0))` gives a polynomial object that represents a least squares fit to $at^3+bt^2+ct = x$. With this, the accelerations at the various ticks is `np.deriv().deriv()(tv)` and the zero to 60 time is `min(np.roots(p.deriv()-88))`.  I don't know how you could do that in Objective C. That's a programming problem rather than a physics problem.

Comment: Interesting, I've never taken the time to learn Python. I see there's an App called Pythonista which compiles to an iPhone, spiffy. Thank you for your time.